# UItabBarController setselectedindex viewWillAppear invoke twice

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
CustomTabBar *tabar = (CustomTabBar*)self.tabBarController;
tabar.previousIndex = tabar.selectedIndex;
tabar.selectedIndex = INDEX_COLLECTION_BOX_VIEW_CONTROLLER;
```

CustomTabBar inherit the uitabbarcontroller and I tap a Buttton ,excute above code but the viewWillAppear for ViewController which index is not `INDEX_COLLECTION_BOX_VIEW_CONTROLLER` also invoke . 
the log is

```
2014-12-03 15:15:08.724 SogalNew[4187:3180974] -[TeamViewController viewWillAppear:] [Line 63] index is:5 <br/>
2014-12-03 15:15:08.774 SogalNew[4187:3180974] -[CollectionController viewWillAppear:] [Line 88] index is:7 <br/>
```

and the Macro is:

```
define INDEX_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_VIEW_CONTROLLER 5
define INDEX_COLLECTION_BOX_VIEW_CONTROLLER 7
define INDEX_TEAM_VIEW_CONTROLLER 8
```

the button which I tap is belong to ViewController that index == `INDEX_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_VIEW_CONTROLLER` .
I  check a long time ,and can't resolve，help me!!

Comment: Where is the above code called? Do you have a delegate for your tab bar controller set?

Comment: called when a button Tap ,no delegate .I check my code careful ,   set  the tabar.selectedIndex only the button tap

Comment: I see the code up there, but can you show *where* (or in which `IBAction`) that code is being called?

Comment: - (IBAction)collectionButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender {
    CustomTabBar *tabar = (CustomTabBar*)self.tabBarController;
    tabar.previousIndex = tabar.selectedIndex;
    tabar.selectedIndex = INDEX_COLLECTION_BOX_VIEW_CONTROLLER;
}

Comment: Just try this code  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: INDEX_COLLECTION_BOX_VIEW_CONTROLLER];

Comment: Hi,I found out the reason ,that is UITabbarViewController lead to that strange performance if have 5 or more viewControllers .I resolve that with<code>
-(void)setSelectedIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedIndex
{
    [super setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];
    
    if([self.moreNavigationController.viewControllers count] > 1)
    {
        //Modify the view stack to remove the More view
        self.moreNavigationController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.moreNavigationController.visibleViewController, nil];
    }
}<code>